# SSRS Error: "Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope"

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

How to reference a textbox that is in an other group and use it in a column header?

Or how can I make column header dynamically changing based on a value in a group.
Page Break is set for each instance of the group, so only one user (of all users) will be on each page.

This expression gives me an error.

=ReportItems!UserName.value

Are there any workaround for that?

[image]

**Able to add total for the group:**

[image]

Comment: You can see if you are really inside the group by right clicking the UserName Row Group item and select Add Total Before.

Comment: Yes, I am able to add total before. So User Name row group is really is a group. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The better way (and quickest) to do this to create a LIST with a single cell (textbox) using the same dataset, grouped by USERNAME with the page breaks and then put the current table in that cell. Then use `Fields!USERNAME.Value` for the User Name text box as usual.

Comment: I am a little confused. So I created a list, inserted a TextBox in it, group List by UserName. Everything works if List with textbox is outside of main tablix. But when I put List with text box in a column header cell and run a report - all users are populated in the header cell. However I need just one

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, however, I still think you may have the column outside of your group scope.

```
=FIRST(ReportItems!UserName.value,"UserName")
```